# Problem with plotting figures side by side

Tags: pdftex, plot, subcaption

I want to plot the figures side by side, so for this I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{rect-dtft-32}
        \caption{caption 1}
        \label{rect-32} 
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bart-dtft-32}
        \caption{caption 2} 
        \label{bart-32}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{hamm-dtft-32}
        \caption{caption 3} 
        \label{hamm-32}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and my result is

[image: resulting figure]

Figures are plotted vertically instead of horizontally. Where am I making a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the empty lines between the `subfigure` environments or use `\hfill` instead of the empty line if you want the first image to align with the left margin while the third image is aligned with the right margin.

Comment: @leandriis works! Thank you!

Comment: @leandriis yes, thank you